When Click on marker in Google Map, App crashes
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    //google map object
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createLocationRequest();


        //init google map fragment to show map.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Customize the map as needed
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        // Add markers for Office with custom icon
        Marker officeMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(office)  // i have added LatLang there
                .title("Office"));

        // Add markers for other locations with custom icons
        // Example: shop
        Marker shopMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(shop) // i have added LatLang there
                .title("Shop"));

    }
    
}

I have created this google map app, its working fine. I have add google api key which is working fine.
now When i Click on any marker added to Google Map, App crashes with. Please help.

Can you please post the crash log as well ?
